# How to solve this simple IE render issue?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Consider this code:

```
<style type="text/css">

ul { clear: both; overflow: hidden; border: 3px solid red; margin-bottom: 10px; }
ul li { display: block; padding: 30px 80px; border: 1px solid green; float: left; }

</style>

<ul>

<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>

</ul>

<ul>

<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>

</ul>
```

In firefox and chrome (and possibly safari and opera too - haven't tested) it appears fine. Meaning the `<li>'s` are within the `<ul>'s` green border.

But in ie (9, 8 and 7) this is not the case. Is there a way to have the ul CONTAIN the lis in ie like it does in the other browsers?

Comment: Have you tried changing `ul` to `overflow: auto` or removing `float: left` from `li`?

Comment: @Wex: The `li` elements are supposed to float - that's part of the layout.

Comment: If they're block-level elements, it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply have IE render your document in in standards mode by adding a [doctype declaration](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/Doctype) to your HTML.

Reason being that only in IE's quirks mode can I imagine your `ul` not containing your `li`s. In standards mode, it *should* render that the same way as other browsers do, as proven by [this jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/mCzGP/1) (view it in IE) which ensures standards mode in its preview pane.